# Is there an equation f(x,y) for a triangle inscribed in a unit square with two rounded corners?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

An on and off project of mine is to come up with a smooth saw tooth function without using a Fourier series, so this question is hopefully related in that a sin wave produced from the inscribed triangle described in the title should describe such a smooth saw tooth function. Below is an image showing what I think this triangle ABC inscribed in the unit square should look like, with increasing iterations of some n leading to ever sharper vertices B and C, while vertex A remains sharp and discontinuous at all iterations of n.

[image: Inscribed Unit Triangle]

Just looking at it looks to me to be hopelessly complicated tbh, so any hints or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

The segment $CB$ can be parametrized  ($A$ is the origin) as 
$$(1, \tan t)$$
where $t\in [-\phi, \phi]$, where $\phi = \arctan \frac{1}{2}$. Now consider a function that it is very close to $1$ on $(-\phi, \phi)$ and $0$ at $\pm \phi$.
For instance, such a function can be $f(t)=1-\left(\frac{x}{\phi}\right)^{2n}$, where $n$ is large. So your curve can be 
$$(f(t), f(t)\tan t)$$ with $t \in [-\phi,\phi]$.